# Replacing underscores with dashes in URL's (Apache)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

> **Edit:** Yikes, the answer was right under my nose. The solution is to replace the underscores FIRST. I simply put those rules above the
>   lower case rule, and it seems to be working fine now.

I want to change my URL's to lower case and replace underscores with dashes. So if a visitor arrives at mysite/World/New_York, the URL will default to mysite/world/new-york.

I took care of the lower case by modifying my httpd.conf file and adding this to my .htaccess file...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z].*) /${tolower:$1} [R]
```

Then I added the following rules to replace underscores with dashes:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_\ ]*)[_\ ](.*?[_\ ].*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_\ ]*)[_\ ]([^_\ ]*) /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

I could have sworn it was working OK, but it isn't working now.

This works fine - mysite/World/New-York; it correctly defaults to mysite/world/new-york

But URL's with underscores only work if they're lower case to begin with; this mysite/world/new_york defaults to new-york.

However, a combination of capital letters and underscore is another story. The URL /world/New_York defaults to mysite/mysite/world/new-york

If I also capitalize the section name - mysite/World/New_York - the page dies (my browser just says "No Data Received").

I've also tried these variations without success...

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

This is what my section rule looks like...

```
RewriteRule ^World/([a-zA-Z0-9()_/-]+)/?$ World/index.php?area=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with: http://regex101.com/r/wV1yC5?

Comment: It's not just a matter of replacing underscores with dashes. As I explained above, that function actually works as long as the characters are all lower case. The problem is how underscores interact with capital letters.